# Can I upload a config file from a previous release in FreeNAS?

Tags: truenas

The motherboard in my FreeNAS system failed and I've since replaced it, now I'm in the process of installing FreeNAS using the most recent Release release (11.1) at the time of writing. Supposedly all my data volumes were safe, and all I need to do is restore the previous configuration file.

The original configuration file was created when the system was running 11.0, can I safely upload it to 11.1 without losing data or configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

FreeNAS Configuration files have nothing to do with the volumes. I believe that you merely need to import the volumes back into the new server, which is supported by ZFS.

Comment: For the record, I uploaded my configuration file from a system that had a failed boot disk running 11.0 to an 11.1 system without any issues and the pool was imported back into the new installation without any manual importation of volumes.
I'm about to try this going from 11.1 to 11.3 now, wish me luck.